# osgi - multiple instances of a service

Tags: soap, client, osgi, multiple-instances

How can I create multiple instances of a bundle that consumes an external webservice?
An external webservice requires clients to logon before using the services. I have multiple accounts. The problem is I want to be able to add multiple instances; one for each account. Each instance is an osgi declarative service that consumes the external service.

Do I have to deploy a new bundle for each account? This does not feel like the right way to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that bundle under your control - can you refactor it ?

If yes, it might be useful to expose a client factory service, rather than client service itself. 
Then each instance can log into a different account.

Comment: the bundle is in my control. I make the bundle using the webservice generated classes.

Comment: does this mean that for each account that I add I have to add another bundle

Comment: no, that's exactly why I recommend factory - calling its `getInstance()` method will create separate instance per each account.

Answer (score 4):

What you need is multiple instances of an OSGi component or service, not multiple instances of a bundle.

I'd recommend a service factory, where each OSGi config that you create (account parameters in your case) for your service causes a new instance of a service to be created.

Neil Bartlett's tutorial at http://njbartlett.name/2010/07/19/factory-components-in-ds.html looks like a good starting point for that.