# Can osgi run multiple instances of the same bundle

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle

What I’m looking to do is to run multiple Clojure environments that start in a pristine mode on the same JVM. It has to be such a way that their namespaces and the generated classes don’t clobber each other.

looking at this question: [osgi - multiple instances of a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241897/osgi-multiple-instances-of-a-service), I need clarification whether running multiple instances of the same service will solve the namespace clobbering issue.

Comment: You are probably asking about `org.osgi.framework.ServiceFactory`. Care to specify how you plan to instantiate the environments? Or who will be doing it?

Comment: @MarcosZolnowski, I want to build a jupyter type environment so that users can create an instance of a notebook, connect to it, do their calculations and then close it when they have finished. The each notebook instance should have environments separated from each other, including loaded classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, apparently you can, if starting the framework with the property `org.osgi.framework.bsnversion=multiple`.

I never tried using that, don't know if would work.

If you want **to isolate** the ClassLoaders, it would be better to just **create a child ClassLoader** for each instance.

Comment: Strictly speaking you *can* install multiple instances of the same bundle/version combination. The OSGi Framework must have been started with the property `org.osgi.framework.bsnversion=multiple` (see [OSGi Core spec](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.core/7.0.0/framework.api.html#org.osgi.framework.Constants.FRAMEWORK_BSNVERSION_MULTIPLE)). However this is not really a solution to the OP's question.

Comment: That is new to me. It was introduced in OSGi 4.3, right?

Comment: Something like that, yes. It was introduced in order to support subsystems. Not a great idea in my opinion.

Comment: I don't think classloader isolation will solve the issue. There may be two classloaders that load the same class and the classes will clobber each other

Comment: @NeilBartlett that might work though I'm not sure how tracking will work for this.